# mod_rewrite stopped working all of a sudden

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following mod_rewrite code in a htaccess file. It's been working perfectly for the past few months since I wrote it. But all of a sudden this morning it completely stopped working. Any ideas how I can troubleshoot this?

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-:/]+)$ index.php?modname=$1
```

** HERE IS MY ORIGINAL FULL CODE - UNEDITED ***

```
ErrorDocument 404 "<H1>Page not found</H1>"
ErrorDocument 403 "<H1>Access denied</H1>"

RewriteEngine On

## REQUIRE SSL RULE
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-:/]+)$ index.php?modname=$1
```

It does seem that mod_rewrite is working, because I followed an online guide and did a basic mod_rewrite like this:

```
RewriteRule cat/(.*)/(.*)/$ /test.php?$1=$2
```

And it seems to work if i open url mydomain/cat/product/123/

*** UPDATE ***

As an interim solution, I have add a custom 404 page like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 error404.php
```

Then in the error404.php file i've included index.php to work the same way as a mod_rewrite was by applying the following code:

```
$modname = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
```

This solves the problem without having mod_rewrite. But it will result in lots of 404 errors in my logfiles and hence I really need to get to the bottom of why the rewriterule isnt working.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: How exactly does it not work? It triggers an error message? It misbehaves in a given way? `.htaccess` file is not parsed?

Comment: the .htaccess file is working because i have a custom 404 code in there. If i go to url: /users/adduser it's supposed to load index.php?modname=users/adduser but i keep getting 404 errors meaning it's not applying the mod_rewrite

Comment: I have not omitted relevant code, I just took out the bit about SSL as that rule was working, but have since edited the post to include that at the bottom. I will now edit the post and add the entire code unmodfied

Comment: I see you edited away the *my host doesnt have mod_rewrite enabled* addition to the question. My comment was referring to that so I'll remove it to avoid confusion.

Comment: What is not working? could you explain in a few words? Are you unable to access ur webpages? Does it return a loop error? or something else

Comment: @Starkeen the rewrite isnt working. i am getting 404 errors. So if i go to for example mydomain.com/users/view-user/1234 that should load index.php?modname=users/view-user/1234 But instead it seems to be looking for the path users/view-user/1234 and not finding it and returning a 404.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the rules you provided. I think you have a brower cache related issue, clear them or try a diffrent browser. or add a rewrite base directive to your rule.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it was working previously as is or not, but you have an error in the regex pattern of the last `RewriteRule` directive. The character set defined is:

```
([\w-:/]+)
```

where, the position of `-` character causes issues. Put the symbol either at the beginning or end of the character set:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(\S+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([-\w:/]+)$ index.php?modname=$1
```

Comment: Is there maybe a much simpler way of doing the above? Basically all i'm trying to do is get the REQUEST_URI of everything after mydomain.com/ and then I am simply trying to apply a RewriteRule rule to put that REQUEST_URI string into index.php?modname=value_of_request_uri

Comment: @Ahmed Can you confirm that `mod-rewrite` is indeed enabled? Put some random characters in htacccess above to break it, and see if the server throws 500 error.

Comment: It doesnt seem to break it, but I have a feeling their is a .htaccess in the outer folder which replaces .php file. However, mod-rewrite must be enabled because if I remove existing code and put RewriteRule cat/(.*)/(.*)/$ /test.php?$1=$2 then this method seems to work

Comment: @Ahmed Provide your folder structure